# Why my cloud application failed to display manipulate element correctly?

Tags: export, variable-definitions, wolfram-cloud

I have:

```
Fence[content_, length_] := Column[{
   Grid[Partition[Characters[content], UpTo[length]]],
   Grid[{Select[
      Flatten[Transpose[
        PadRight[
         Partition[Characters[content], 
          UpTo[length]], {Ceiling[Length[Characters[content]]/length],
           length}, "@@"]]], # != "@@" &]}]
   }]
Mani[content_] := 
 Manipulate[Fence[content, x], {x, 1, Length[Characters[content]], 1}]
```

Then test it in my desktop *Mathematica* and everything goes well:

[image]

So I deploy:

```
CloudDeploy[Mani["0123456789"], Permissions -> "Public"]
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ea1707d8-8c50-4926-bfad-207c5c1c1430"]
```

But it seems doesn't evaluate my function(`Fence`):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation and `Details ans Options` section for `CloudDeploy` are saying:

> CloudDeploy[expr,...] automatically deploys all definitions needed to evaluate expr, much like CloudSave.

and as we can see, it's not the case here. Or, it's a feature of `Manipulate` which boxes definitions are got by `FrontEnd` so maybe `evaluation` doesn't apply here.

At the end, you can force them to be remembered by using `SaveDefinitions`:

```
Mani[content_] :=  Manipulate[
  Column@{Fence[content, x], DownValues@Fence}, 
  {x, 1, Length[Characters[content]], 1}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I find you changed my code a little(Looks cleaner than mine). Could you please post it in your answer?

Comment: @Sayakiss I only added `Column` with `Fence` definitions for preview.

Comment: I find my cloud app is very slow, how to optimize my code to get an more fluent app?

Comment: @Sayakiss You can't, each time something is meant to be updated it has to call cloud and send results to you.

Comment: It's really disappointing... I think I should deploy a simple HTML page with a single JavaScript to do that task..

Comment: @Sayakiss you are not the only one who feels this way. WRI cloud development team is working on allowing some things to be done client side but this was mentioned 1.5 year earlier and a base cloud is still beta so I'm not expecting this to be anywhere soon.

Comment: Really thanks for providing that information kindly!