# Self contained APIFunction. Collecting definitions

Tags: bugs, documentation, wolfram-cloud, deployment, development

**Bug fixed in V11.2**

Previously dependencies collector failed to collect `check` if `check` was only mentioned in *lhs*: `foo[x_?check] := $Failed;`

---

[**Cross posted on community.wolfram.com**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1118734)

#### Background

After failed attempt (1) to create a complex API, by nicely linking my `APIFunction` to a cloud based package, I decided to go with the flow and trust that:

> `CloudDeploy[expr, ...]` automatically deploys all definitions needed to evaluate expr, much like `CloudSave`.

#### Problem

but either it can't be trusted or I'm missing the point. It seems that definitions are collected by scanning right-hand-sides of related definitions but not left-hand-sides.

#### Example

```
ClearAll[foo, check];
check = IntegerQ;
foo[x_?check] := $Failed;
foo[x_] := x^2

api = CloudDeploy[
    APIFunction[{"x" -> "Number"}, foo[#x] &]
  , Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

```
foo[2]     (* -> $Failed*)
foo[1.2]   (* -> 1.44 *)
```

```
URLExecute[api, {"x" -> 2}]    (* -> 4*) !!!!!!!!!!!
URLExecute[api, {"x" -> 1.2}]  (* -> 1.44*)
```

The first `URLExecute` is wrong, it is caused by missing definition of `check`.

One can confirm that by

```
Import[api, "Text"]
```

> ```
> Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = Language`DefinitionList[ 
>   HoldForm[foo] -> {..., DownValues -> {
>     HoldPattern[foo[(x_)?check]] :> $Failed, 
>     HoldPattern[foo[x_]] :> x^2
>     }, ...
>  }];
>
> APIFunction[{"x" -> "Number"}, foo[#x] & ]
> ```

#### Questions

- Is this expected? Are there any new guidelines how to write code so it could be collected well? Or is it a flaw in `` Language` ``?
- Is there anything I could read to learn working with the Cloud features in such a way that I won't have to come back here with a question/problem about a basic issue like deployment of dependencies?

#### Links

1. [Clean package update for API/FormFunctions on Wolfram Cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147330/5478)
2. [Why my cloud application failed to display manipulate element correctly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104739/5478)
3. [Using CloudDeploy with dependent functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125837/5478)

Comment: `foo[x_?check] := (Hold[check]; $Failed);` will work. This kind of new cloud programming paradigm ("mention all symbols somewhere on the right of := ") should probably be followed until the Wolfram Cloud system stays in its current beta-phase and until it is properly documented. I heard that better documentation is being worked on. And that is promising. (Andre?).

Comment: I added [tag:documentation]+[tag:bugs] as WRI confirmed it is a "limitation". A limitation not mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably not a direct answer to the question, but too long for a comment. Regarding the collection of definitions, I can offer a hack which seems to work (I did answer this question before on a [Russian-speaking Mathematica forum](https://vk.com/wall-1172233_27406?reply=27484)). The idea is to use Manipulate to collect the dependencies. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[extractDefinitions];
SetAttributes[extractDefinitions,HoldAllComplete];
extractDefinitions[code_]:=
  Block[{$ContextPath},
    DeleteCases[
      First @ Cases[
        MakeBoxes[#]& @ Manipulate[code,SaveDefinitions->True],
        Verbatim[RuleDelayed][Initialization,rhs_]:>HoldComplete[rhs],
        Infinity
      ],
      x_Set/;!FreeQ[Unevaluated[x],HoldPattern[Typeset`initDone$$]],
      Infinity
    ]
  ];

ClearAll[embedDependencies];
embedDependencies[APIFunction[params_,f_,rest___]]:=
  With[{initCode=extractDefinitions[f]},
    APIFunction[params,(ReleaseHold[initCode];f[#])&]
  ]
```

Now you can do:

```
ClearAll[foo, check];
check = IntegerQ;
foo[x_?check] := x;
foo[x_] := x^2
```

(I slightly modified your example). Now, here is the result of `embedDependencies`:

```
embedDependencies[APIFunction[{"x" -> "Number"}, foo[#x] &]]

(*
APIFunction[
  {"x" -> "Number"}, 
  (ReleaseHold[HoldComplete[CompoundExpression[
    {foo[x_?check] := x, foo[x_] := x^2, x = True,check = IntegerQ}]]];
    (foo[#x] &)[#1]
  ) &
]
*)
```

And this works fine when deployed:

```
api = CloudDeploy[
  embedDependencies[APIFunction[{"x" -> "Number"}, foo[#x] &]], 
  Permissions -> "Public"
];


URLExecute[api, {"x" -> 2}]
URLExecute[api, {"x" -> 1.2}]

(* 2 *)

(* 1.44 *)
```

This is of course a hack, so while I feel it is rather reliable, I can give no guarantees here.