# PatternTest vs Parallelization

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, parallelization

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.2**

---

Consider the following function

```
slowNorm[x_?(Length[#] == 3 && VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] :=
  (Pause[1]; Norm[x])
```

An equivalent implementation is

```
latticePoint3DQ = (Length[#] == 3 && VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &);
slowNormAlt[x_?latticePoint3DQ] := (Pause[1]; Norm[x])
```

However, only the first function can be parallelized efficiently (in both cases all subkernels are already running):

```
In[1]:= ParallelTable[
          slowNorm[{i, 0, 0}], {i, 1, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[1]= {2.01148, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

In[2]:= ParallelTable[
          slowNormAlt[{i, 0, 0}], {i, 1, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[2]= {5.00941, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

Using Condition instead of PatternTest does result in the same behavior.

Is there a way to check arguments using `latticePoint3DQ` without losing the ability to parallelize?

Edit: I am using Version 11.1.1.0 of MMA and the Platform is Linux x86 (64-bit)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Can you specify your M version and give even mores pecific, step by step instructions?  (E.g. the above does not show when the parallel kernels are launched, which takes a considerable time.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, I've edited the post, I don't know if I can add anymore step by step instrucitons.

Comment: I asked for step by step because I wanted to make sure that you were not timing the subkernel startup.  It's irrelevant now because I can easily reproduce this in 11.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this in 11.1.1 but *not* in 11.2 or later.  I believe that the problem is that the definitions of `latticePoint3DQ` are not automatically distributed (*probably* because symbols in `PatternTest` and `Condition` are not being considered), thus `slowNormAlt` effectively ends up being evaluated on the main kernel.

The fix is simple:

```
DistributeDefinitions[latticePoint3DQ]
```

---

**Update:** This is very likely a problem with `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``, discussed in this QA:

- [Self contained APIFunction. Collecting definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148207/self-contained-apifunction-collecting-definitions)

Comment: If `DistributeDefinitions` uses `ExtendedFullDefinition` then this is it: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148207/self-contained-apifunction-collecting-definitions

Comment: @Kuba Very likely it's the same but I won't read the code to confirm. I suggest you mark one as duplicate of the other.

Comment: No need to: ``PrintDefinitions @ Parallel`Protected`DistDefs``